# Going back from a view and changing the orientation

Tags: ios, iphone, rotation, orientation

With SDK8.1  I allow Portrait orientation, Landscape left and right on .plist. I have

1) A navigation controller

```
@implementation OrientationRespectfulNavigationController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    BOOL retVal = [super shouldAutorotate];

    if (self.topViewController)
        retVal = [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];

    return retVal;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSUInteger retVal = [super supportedInterfaceOrientations];

    if (self.topViewController)
        retVal = [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];

    return retVal;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
     UIInterfaceOrientation retVal = [super preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];

    if (self.topViewController)
        retVal = [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];

    return retVal;
}
```

2) UIViewController A

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return  UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

2) UIViewController B

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

So, I start the app in portrait. I see the ViewController A. Then I push to ViewController B also in portrait. Then I rotate the mobile and B change to landscape. OK. But, why when I go back ViewController A appears in landscape? How I can force A still always in portrait? I prove a lot of things and I can't find a solution in stackoverflow

Thanks

Comment: Return YES from -shouldAutorotate.